# Two sides of a triangle are 15cm and 20cm long respectively...

Tags: calculus

Two sides of a triangle are $15cm$ and $20cm$ long respectively. How fast is the third side increasing if the angle between the given sidesis $60$ degrees and is increasing at therate of $2deg/sec$? I tried solving it using the phythagorean theorem but I wasn't able to use $60 degrees$ so I was thinking my answer is wrong.

Comment: Try using the law of cosines instead -- nothing was said about the triangle being a RIGHT triangle, which is required for the Pythagorean theorem to apply.

Comment: You can only use the Phythagorean Theorem for right triangles. Try the cosine formula. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the cosine rule: $$a^2=b^2+c^2 -2bc \cos \theta$$ where $b$ and $c$ are fixed at 15 and 20, while the angle is changing but remember to convert from degrees to radians!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the third side is given by the law of cosines as:

$$c^2 = (15)^2 + (20)^2 - (2)(15)(20)\cos\theta$$

where $\theta$ is the given angle.

Another hint: would be easier to do implicit differentiation. And remember the Chain Rule. You're trying to find the derivative of both sides with respect to time.

Final hint: in calculus, you should pretty much always work with radian measure, so if you're given something in degrees, convert first!

Comment: so the c side is $34.59$ but what will be my $da/dt$ and $db/dt$ ? are they both the rate of $2def/sec$?

Comment: is it 3.95? the $dc/dt$

Comment: I'm getting $\displaystyle \frac{dc}{dt}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt {39}} \approx 0.503 cms^{-1}$.